# octopus-graph tikz/pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, external-files

EDIT:I found a solution. See below.

i'm trying to get something like this:[image]

I have small dots and big dots, and some small dots are connected to one big dot. I can "plot" all points with pgfplots:

```
\addplot[scatter,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square*,blue},%
        b={mark=triangle*,red},%
        d={mark=triangle*,green},%
        c={mark=o,draw=black}}]
         table[x=xs, y=ys, meta=qs] {test.txt};
    \end{axis}
```

But i can't figure out, how to add the connection between single dots.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
\foreach \x1/\y1/\x2/\y2 in data{
\draw (\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y2); 
}
```

Or is there a better way? Btw: All data are generated by myself, therefore it is no problem to change the format.

EDIT:
A MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
\addplot[scatter,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square*,blue},%
        b={mark=triangle*,red},%
        d={mark=triangle*,green},%
        c={mark=o,draw=black}}]
         table[x=xs, y=ys, meta=qs] {testoutput.txt};
%add here?
        \end{axis}
%or here?
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with testoutput.txt

```
xs xs ys qs
155 725 d 
195 1215 c 
1095 825 c 
245 2665 b 
395 2850 d 
1670 2875 t 
15 2660 t 
270 1960 t
1715 3010 t
1085 1110 t
1040 685 t
1985 1535 t
580 170 t
2250 2025 t
1815 2925 t
1420 3370 t
160 1125 t
25 500 t
460 640 t
100 70 t
375 170 t
1185 360 t
```

And then there is an other file connection.dat

```
155 725 1670 2875
155 725 270 1960
155 725 100 70
155 725 1185 360
1095 825 715 2660
1095 825 1715 3010
1095 825 580 170
```

It is not sure, which connections i have to made, not until the data is generated.

EDIT2:

```
     \DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{conns}{connections.dat}
     \DTLforeach*{conns}{\xA=x, \yA=y, \xB=a, \yB=b}{%
            \addplot[
                color=gray]
                coordinates {
                (\xA,\yA )(\xB,\yB)         
                };  }
```

But now i have a little perfomance problem. My datas are big: around 1000 dots and ~500 connections per graph! And i need to plot 8 of them. The time to compile my tex is more than 1.5 minutes! Is there a way to "precompile" the graphs?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the generated data and a full MWE?  You can do exactly what you want, excepting of course the need to use `\x, \y, \a, and \b` (say) because you can't have digits in csnames :)

Comment: I think my only problem is to read correctly from my connection.dat file.

Comment: How do you decide which connections to be drawn or to which point?

Comment: This is quite complex. Let say, it's random. Btw: i found a solution.

Comment: @ChuckZee Don't be this guy: http://xkcd.com/979; post your solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can plot the `connections.dat` file using the `scatter` plot style and a couple of `visualization depends on` statements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents}{testoutput.txt}
xs ys qs
155 725 d 
195 1215 c 
1095 825 c 
245 2665 b 
395 2850 d 
1670 2875 t 
15 2660 t 
270 1960 t
1715 3010 t
1085 1110 t
1040 685 t
1985 1535 t
580 170 t
2250 2025 t
1815 2925 t
1420 3370 t
160 1125 t
25 500 t
460 640 t
100 70 t
375 170 t
1185 360 t
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{connections.dat}
155 725 1670 2875
155 725 270 1960
155 725 100 70
155 725 1185 360
1095 825 15 2660
1095 825 1715 3010
1095 825 580 170
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
\addplot[scatter,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square*,blue},%
        b={mark=triangle*,red},%
        d={mark=triangle*,green},%
        c={mark=o,draw=black}}]
         table[x=xs, y=ys, meta=qs] {testoutput.txt};
\addplot [
    scatter, only marks, mark=none,
    visualization depends on=\thisrowno{0}\as\startx,
    visualization depends on=\thisrowno{1}\as\starty,
    visualization depends on=\thisrowno{2}\as\endx,
    visualization depends on=\thisrowno{3}\as\endy,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \draw (0,0) -- (axis direction cs:{\endx-\startx},{\endy-\starty});
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={},
] table {connections.dat};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution by myself. I will try yours as soon as possible.

Comment: @ChuckZee: I don't think it's a good idea to accept this answer if you haven't even tried it out. Could you please post your own solution as an answer and accept that?

Answer (score 1):

My solution with the package `datatool`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
\addplot[scatter,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square*,blue},%
        b={mark=triangle*,red},%
        d={mark=triangle*,green},%
        c={mark=o,draw=black}}]
         table[x=xs, y=ys, meta=qs] {testoutput.txt};


     \DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{conns}{connections.dat}
     \DTLforeach*{conns}{\xA=x, \yA=y, \xB=a, \yB=b}{%
            \addplot[color=gray]
                coordinates {
                (\xA,\yA )(\xB,\yB) };  
            }

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using one `\addplot` command per connecting line, I would recommend using `\draw [gray] (axis cs:\xA,\yA) -- (axis cs:\xB,yB);`. That is *much* more efficient than sending every line through the whole plot processing mechanism.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are connecting each point with the previous point. But in your question you want them to connect to a common point.

Comment: @percusse: I think ChuckZee is assuming a `connections.dat` file like the one in his question, where each line contains two coordinates (xA, yA, xB, yB), and the first coordinate would be the common points (in the example that would be `(155,725)` and `(1095,825)`)

Comment: @Jake That's pretty redundant I would say, before anything reading two extra columns with the identical info for all rows

Comment: @percusse: I agree. They're not necessarily *all* identical, though. In ChuckZee's example image, there are six different common points, for example.

Comment: @Jake, using '\draw' instead of '\addplot' sounds reasonable.  But when i use it, then there is only 1 line drawn (the last one)